# Dijkstra's algorithm on graphs with generic type vertices

Tags: java, generics

I have implemented graphs as a `class Graph<E>`.
Here, `E` denotes the type of vertex (integer, character, etc.).
The class has an adjacency (hash) map `<E, Set<E>>` as a field that takes vertices as keys and puts them in the set of vertices that which the key is adjacent to.
Moreover, there is a weight map `<E, <E, Double>>` that that takes two vertices as keys and puts them in the respective weight of the edge.

Now, I want to make a new class pertaining to Dijkstra's algorithm.
This will contain a distance function `<E, <E, Double>>` that that takes two vertices as keys and puts them in the respective distance. The problem is how can the Dijkstra class figure out the what `E` is?

I have managed to implement it within the same class, but that clutters the class too much and I want to separate it. I want a `Dijkstra` class that will accept a `Graph<E>` as parameter and do the job.

This is what I have currently.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Graph<E>{
    Map<E, Set<E>> adj; //Adjacency map; v |-> {u in V | u is adjacent to v}
    Map<E, Map<E, Double>> weight; //Weight map; (u,v) |-> w(u,v)

    Map<E, Map<E, Double>> dist; //distance map; (u,v) |-> d(u,v)

    Graph(){
        adj = new HashMap<>();
        weight = new HashMap<>();
        dist = new HashMap<>();
    }

    //Accessors
    Set<E> getVertices(){
        return adj.keySet();
    }
    Set<E> getAdjacency(E a){
        return adj.get(a);
    }
    double getWeight(E a, E b){
        return weight.get(a).get(b);
    }

    //Mutators
    void addVertex(E v){
        adj.computeIfAbsent(v, k -> new HashSet<>());
    }
    void setWeight(E u, E v, double d){
        weight.computeIfAbsent(u, k -> new HashMap<>());
        weight.get(u).put(v,d);
    }
    void addEdge(E u, E v, double d){
        addVertex(u);
        addVertex(v);
        adj.get(u).add(v);
        setWeight(u,v,d);
    }
    void addEdgebothways(E u, E v, double w){
        addEdge(u,v,w);
        addEdge(v,u,w);
    }

    //------------Dijkstra
    E findMinimal(Set<E> T, E s){ //finds the vertex with minimal estimate
        Iterator<E> itr = T.iterator();
        E min = itr.next();
        for(E i : T){
            if(dist.get(s).get(i) < dist.get(s).get(min)){
                min = i;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    void doDijkstra(E s){
        Set<E> T = new HashSet<>(getVertices()); //set of unexplored vertices
        E u; //vertex to explore
        dist.put(s, new HashMap<>());
        for(E x: getVertices()){
            dist.get(s).put(x, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        }
        dist.get(s).put(s, 0.0);

        while(!T.isEmpty()){
            u = findMinimal(T, s);
            T.remove(u);
            for(E v : T){
                if(getAdjacency(u).contains(v)){
                    if(dist.get(s).get(v) > dist.get(s).get(u) + getWeight(u,v)){
                    dist.get(s).put(v,  dist.get(s).get(u) + getWeight(u,v));
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Graph<Character> G = new Graph<>();
        G.addEdgebothways('A', 'B', 3);
        G.addEdgebothways('A', 'C', 2);
        G.addEdgebothways('B', 'C', 2);
        G.addEdgebothways('C', 'D', 3);
        G.addEdgebothways('B', 'D', 1);
        G.addVertex('E');

        G.doDijkstra('A');
        G.doDijkstra('B');
        System.out.println(G.dist);
    }
}
```